# Throttling EF queries to save DTUs

Tags: azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

We have an asp.Net application using EF 6 hosted in Azure. The database runs at about 20% DTU usage for most of the time except for certain rare actions.
These are almost like db dumps in Excel format, like having all orders of the last X years etc. which the (power) users can trigger and then get the result later by email.

The problem is that these queries use up all DTU and the whole application goes into a crawl. We would like to kind of throttle these non-critical queries as it doesn't matter if this takes 10-15min longer.

Googling I found the option to reduce the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY but this wont fix the issue of using up all resources.

Thanks for any pointers, ideas or solutions.

Comment: there's no ready to use tool, you'll need to query in chunks. Rather than select *, use select top 100 and paging till the end.

Comment: You can use the query store to look for the expensive queries and see if they are optimal/can be tuned.  Sometimes the translation is just bad and inefficient.  Additionally, if you have a premium/business critical DB, you can try offloading the big read-only queries to the readable secondary.  Finally, in the worst case, you could (at some additional cost) restore a copy of the DB to service requests like this to separate the load from the main transactional workload.  (and then delete the extra DB later)

Comment: Optimizing is going to be hard as it is more or less a db dump. We do not have a readonly version of the database as this would be overkill/exceed our budget.

Reading in chunks means we would need to sleep (?) in-between or the whole paging would be pointless as the amount of data read would just be stretched over multiple queries but not over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Optimizing is going to be hard as it is more or less a db dump.

Azure SQL Database doesn't have [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver15) available, so you'll have to handle this in code.

Azure SQL Database runs in READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT mode, so slowing down the session that dumps the data from a table (or any streaming query plan) should reduce its DTU consumption without adversely affecting other sessions.

To do this put waits in the loop that reads the query results, either an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` returned from a LINQ query or a `SqlDataReader` returned from an ADO.NET `SqlCommand`.

But you'll have to directly loop over the streaming results.  You can't copy the query results into memory first using `IQueryable<TEntity>.ToList()` or `DataTable.Load()`, `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()`, etc as that would read as fast as possible.

eg

```
var results = new List<TEntity>();
int rc = 0;
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
     rc++;
     var e = new TEntity();
     e.Id = dr.GetInt(0);
     e.Name = dr.GetString(1);
     //  ...
     results.Add(e);
     
     if (rc%100==0)
       Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(100);
   }
}
```

or

```
var results = new List<TEntity>();
int rc = 0;
foreach (var e in db.MyTable.AsEnumerable())
{
   rc++;
   var e = new TEntity();
   e.Id = dr.GetInt(0);
   e.Name = dr.GetString(1);
   //  ...
   results.Add(e);

   if (rc%100==0)
     Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(100);

}
```

For extra credit, use async waits and stream the results directly to the client without batching in memory.

Alternatively, or in addition, you can limit the number of sessions that can concurrently perform the dump to one, or one per table, etc using named [Application Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is what I would have done next but good to know that I was on the right track. Plan on creating a .AsThrottledEnumerable() or similar extension which reads a record, sleeps, reads a record, etc for reuse.